# Admob Interstitial ad not showing fullScreen on devices iOS

Tags: ios, swift, admob, interstitial

I made a game using spritekit and implement admob interstitial ad following the documentation provided by google. Everything works fine in the simulator, the ad presents fullscreen as expected in the right time. The problem is that when I run in my iPhone 6s the ad doesn't fill the entire screen, just a small part of it on a black screen. I've implemented all the admob code on my gameviewController and call it in a gameScene using a observer.

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

```
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameViewController.showIntersticialAd), name: Notification.Name("showIntersticialAd"), object: nil)

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        let scene = MenuScene(size: view.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        view.presentScene(scene)

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = false
        view.showsNodeCount = false
    }
}

@objc func showIntersticialAd() {
    if interstitial.isReady {
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    } else {
        print("Ad not ready")
    }
}
```

}

extension GameViewController: GADInterstitialDelegate {

```
func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-4828696079960529/6898313363")
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.load(GADRequest())
    return interstitial
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}
```

}

I've searched a lot in the internet and in the admob documentation but didn't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: capture logs and update in your question

Comment: I had the same issue. Only part of the screen was covered with ad content, but other areas are just black.

Answer (score -2):

`@objc func showIntertialAds() { 
   if !interstitial.isReady{ 
      interstitial.load(GADRequest()) 
  } if interstitial.isReady { 
      interstitial.present(fromRootViewController:(UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController)!) 
  } 
}`